# How to do unit testing for foreign key inserted properly or not

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a One order and it has many orderitems now foreign key is generated of order in orderitem so i have to check that every orderitems get proper Order foreign key.That means Orderid in orderitem should be equal to that particular Order.What should come in assert?

My Domain class is as follows

```
public class Order

{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Location FromLocation { get; set; }
    public Location ToLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDispatch> OrderDispatches { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }


}



[TestMethod]

public void OrderItemsAreAssignProperOrderId()
{

   using (var db = new StockWatchContext())

   {

            Order o = new Order();



            o.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
            o.Status = OrderStatus.Open;
            o.Employee = db.Employees.Find(8);
            o.FromLocation = db.Locations.Find(4);
            o.ToLocation = db.Locations.Find(1);

            o.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem> {
            new OrderItem {Product = db.Products.Find(1), Quantity = 10}, 

            };

            db.Orders.Add(o);


            db.SaveChanges();

            Assert.AreEqual();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should share your original method first.In which we can see that what you want to test in unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing against a database dedicated to tests, you can empty the tables before every TestMethod.

Then after the SaveChanges in OrderItemsAreAssignProperOrderId() method check whether all rows in the OrderItem table have the correct Order id.